# Derivative of the expected value of a function

Tags: probability, statistics, derivatives, expected-value, economics

Suppose we have random variables $\theta$ and $c$. We want to maximize the expected value of the following function with respect to $q$:
$$E_{\theta, c}[V(q(\theta,c),\theta)-C(q(\theta,c),c)]$$
where $E_{\theta, c}$ is taking the expected value with respect to both $\theta$ and $c$. The above expression was copied directly from the text I'm working with, although I'm not quite sure if it's accurate in that $q$ is a choice variable who's optimized value will depend on $\theta$ and $c$, but the variable itself is not a function of $\theta$ and $c$ (sorry if this is confusing). Thus, I suppose we're trying to solve the following:
$$q^* = \underset{q}{\arg\max}\ E_{\theta, c}[V(q,\theta)-C(q,c)]$$
The text then claims that this would be the as solving:
$$q^*(\theta,c) = \underset{q}{\arg\max} \{V(q,\theta)-C(q,c)\}$$
I was wondering if this is generally true and what is the reasoning behind this. Because intuitively it seems that the text implies 
$$\underset{q}{\arg\max} \{V(q,\theta)-C(q,c)\} = \underset{q}{\arg\max}\ E_{\theta, c}[V(q,\theta)-C(q,c)]$$

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why this should be true in general. However, it just might be the case that for the specific form of $V$ and $C$ and also the probability distribution of $\theta, c$, this statement is true. Do you have more information about the functions or the distributions?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Yeah, I believe both $V$ and $C$ are differentiable (continuous) with respect to $q$ and that $V_q, C_q>0$ (subscript denoting partials). Further, $V(0,\theta)=C(0,c)=0$. Lastly, $V_\theta, C_c>0$ and $V_{q,\theta},C_{q,c}>0$. I've read somewhere we move the differentiation inside the expected value if the function is uniformly bounded by some other random variable. If that's true, then my guess is that the claim would hold, but I'm not 100% sure about this.